# Array java help needed

Tags: java

I have this program that takes user input and displays the number of times each integer is entered. I pretty much have it down pat but need another loop to omit the shown occurrence of 0. In other words any number with 0 in it cannot be read, also for some reason i am getting two outputs from the same number in my program. For example, if I enter `3,3` I will get `3 occurs 1 time` and `3 occurs 2 times` as output. The 2 times one being correct and the first one being incorrect.

```
public class Six_Three {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("enter integers between 1 and 100: ");
    int[] num = new int[100];
    int data = input.nextInt();

    while ((data = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
        num[data]++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) { 
        if (num[i] > 0) 
            System.out.println(i + " occurs " + num[i] + " times ");
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, please add the `homework` tag

Comment: Also show your expected output as well i.e in addition to what is currently happening makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You need two separate loops: the first to gather the information, and the second to print the results:

```
int data = 0;

while ((data = input.nextInt()) != 0)
{
    num[data]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    if (num[i] != 0) { /* print num[i] */ }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear, i apologize and thank you for the help as of yet, first off yes this is homework but i do care to learn since i want to program one day, second @Kerreck SB when i try your solution i get a boolean required and int found error, from this line ,while (data = input.nextInt()), obviously it is referencing data which is of int variable but how do i fix that? Thank you all for the input.

Comment: @Jason: Sorry, my C++ habits forgot that you need an explicit bool in Java. I updated the answer to accommodate for that. (In C++, a non-zero int is automatically "true".)

Comment: ok i am getting the desired results other than one issues, i am not reading in the first number the user inputs, i know someone touched on it but it seems to have been deleted, my original post has been updated with the current code, thank you.

Comment: Don't call `nextInt()` outside the loop -- everything happens inside the loop now. I'll add that to the code.

Comment: ok , awesome that worked, thank you so much, im just confused as to why not ask for nextInt() outside the loop when that would be right after i prompted the user for input no? Either way it works and i now know why i was always having that issue with my code, thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Well, think about how the loop works: Each round, you ask for a number, and if the number is non-zero, the loop body exectutes. If the number is zero, the loop breaks and you continue below.

Comment: ok therefor if i am understanding right asking for data through     int data = input.nextInt() , before the loop is outside the loop parameters we set up therefor rendering nothing, i think i got it, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are printing an output every time an integer is read.  Your program is behaving as expected.

To get what you want, you need to scan *all* the input *before* you produce any output.

Try this instead:

```
        while (data != 0){
            data = input.nextInt();
            num[data]++;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) { // your version is 0...99, else array index out of bounds
            if (num[i] > 0) 
                System.out.println(i + " occurs " + num[i] + " times ");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the `num` array after your while loop to print the counts.

```
for (int index = 0; index < num.length; index++) {

    if (num[index] != 0)
        System.out.println(data + " occurs " + num[data] + " time(s).");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you write it the last number has to be 0 to make the scanning stop.  It might be a good idea to check if there's another int available and use that as a condition for the scanning loop.  That way your program can accept any integer.

```
while (input.hasNextInt()){
    num[input.nextInt()]++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it's so simple

```
    int data = 0;

    int[] num = new int[100];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < num.length) {
        if ((data = input.nextInt()) == 0)
            break;

        num[i] = data;
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        int times = 0;
        if (num[i] != 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                if (num[j] == 0) {
                    break;
                } else if (num[i] == num[j]) {
                    times++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(num[i] + " occurs " + times + " times ");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```